# Ellipsized textview not moving in android

Tags: android, textview

i try to work news bar and the text in bar will moving and moving again

problem in the state

the text  nothing move

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mylinenews"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="text moving text moving  text moving text moving text moving  "
            android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very long lasting bug whose information is [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882). Seems that additionally to all the parameters you've set, it's necessary to make the `View` selected to make it work as you may read [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5364). So, basically, what you have to do programmatically is something like this:

```
final TextView mylinenews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mylinenews);
mylinenews.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Textview only rotates with ellipsize if it has the focus.

Comment: i do it by put 
android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
but not change happen